# VFR Reader search functionality

Tags: ios, search, pdf, vfr-reader

Hi just downloaded the VFR-Reader. Its fantastic [exactly what I wanted] except it doesn't have search functionality included...

Does a fork exist that has this implemented? Otherwise what is the best method to include this functionality

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add search functionality by using another project - PDFKitten. I'm using them both in my own project and they work perfectly fine!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you used kitten?